# how can we provide different submit buttons in jsp, and execute respective page of button.?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to know how can we have different buttons in jsp, and how to submit the respective page for the button we pressed.

I have tried fallowing code :

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
   <%-- scriptlet here --%>
   <%
       if(request.getParameter("btnSubmit_1")!=null)
        {
            // means submit_1  is pressed.
            // in java script we do give action as fallows
            /**document.frm2.action="sub-faconline.jsp";
            //document.frm2.target="right_f";
            //document.frm2.submit();****
            my question how can we do above java script code in scriplet in jsp
         }
       else if(request.getParameter("btnSubmit_2")!=null)
       {

           // i want to give some jsp page name here for action. 
        }
   %>



   <form name="frm2" method="post">
   <input type="button" id="btnSubmit_1" name="btnSubmit_1" value="btnSubmit_1" />
  <input type="button" id="btnSubmit_2" name="btnSubmit_2" value="btnSubmit_2"/> 
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your html to this:

```
<form name="frm2" method="post" action="myJsp.jsp">
  <input type="button" id="btnSubmit_1" name="btnSubmit_1" onClick="submitForm('btnSubmit_1'); value="btnSubmit_1"" />
  <input type="button" id="btnSubmit_2" name="btnSubmit_2" onClick="submitForm('btnSubmit_2'); value="btnSubmit_2"/> 
  <input type="hidden" id="btnPressed" name="btnPressed" value=""/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function submitForm(elem){
  document.getElementById("btnPressed").value=elem;
  document.frm2.submit();
}
```

And then in your jsp you can get the button value that was pressed using:

```
request.getParameter("btnPressed");
```

Explanation: Create an invisible input in the form that will hold the value of the btn. Then attach onclick functionality to each of the buttons that will set the value of the hidden input. And then submit the form to the form's action URL. Then in that url, you can get the hidden input's value(that contains the value of the button that was pressed)

Comment: there is none, posting a form with get or post is the only way